# Are Symfony's forms not linkable?

Tags: php, symfony, entity, symfony-forms

i'm developing a light application with Symfony2 framework.

So, i need to create a form without link with an entity ; because the entity i want to fill is not fine to work with forms.

Any ideas ?

Thank's to everybody !

Comment: [something similar like this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754526/symfony2-create-form-without-entity-class)

Comment: You can use an array instead of an entity/object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this link is very useful to answer to the problem :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class

Thank's to everybody for your answers !

Answer (score 2):

Yes Symfony supports forms that are not linked to Entities, the following snippet shows how you cant create a contact form that is not bound to an Entity.

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
    ->setAction($this->generateUrl('contact_route'))
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->add('name', 'text')
    ->add('email', 'email')
    ->add('phone', 'text')
    ->add('message', 'textarea')
    ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'SUBMIT'))
    ->getForm()
    ;

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

         $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject(''.$form->get('name')->getData() ."  ". $form->get('phone')->getData())
        ->setFrom($form->get('email')->getData())
        ->setTo('email@ehost.com')
        ->setBody(''.$form->get('email')->getData().' '.$form->get('message')->getData());
        $this->addFlash('notice','Thank you, we will contact you soon!');
        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);


        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('contact_route'));

    }

    return $this->render('BundleName:Contact:index.html.twig',array('form' => $form->createView(),));
}
```